# Deploying multiple contracts (.sol files) to one contract address

Tags: solidity, truffle

As an exercise, I am trying to deploy a large contract that is greater than the 24kB limit imposed by the Spurious Dragon hardfork. So, I am looking at Uniswap V3 as an aim and my goal is to deploy a fork of Uniswap V3 as an exercise.

Running truffle migrate with UniswapV3Router.sol as a target results in a contract that is ~125kB which is greater than the 24kB limit.The compiler replaces all import statements in UniswapV3Router.sol with the code/library being imported. So, essentially UniswapV3Router.sol becomes a 3000 line of code file. So there is the problem, since that is a very large contract.

This is where UniswapV3Router.sol is deployed on etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code where there are cleary 34 individual contracts uploaded as illustrated by: [image]

So, how to deploy multiple .sol files to the same contract address? In other words, how to achieve the same result as shown on etherscan?

Comment: This is strange indeed. As far as I know, the address to which you deploy a contract is a random one. Not sure how would one set a multitude of smart contracts on the same address. (Good question, I am interested in the answer too)

Comment: Can someone confirm whether EIP-2535: Diamonds and the use of delegatecalls is going in the right direction as a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The contract SwapRounter [inherits](https://solidity-by-example.org/inheritance/) a couple of contracts/interfaces  and embeds a number of [internal libaries](https://solidity-by-example.org/library/).
Additional interfaces are needed to allow the contract to interact with other contracts (such as IERC20).

As stated by etherscan, only the **SwapRouter.sol** contract was deployed at this address.
To reduce the contract size, you can turn on the [Solidity Optimizer](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/internals/optimizer.html) (like the [Uniswap team](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/9161f9ae4aaa109f7efdff84f1df8d4bc8bfd042/hardhat.config.ts#L55)).

Edit: They have used [1.000.000 optimizer runs](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code#L4).

Comment: Am I missing something where the interfaces and internal libraries each exist at separate contract addresses? If so, are they somehow included during compilation or deployment?

Comment: On etherscan they are only shown as separate files that have been checked this way. You can try to verify a flattened contract and it should look different. Internal libraries are [embedded](https://medium.com/coinmonks/all-you-should-know-about-libraries-in-solidity-dd8bc953eae7#:~:text=Internal%3A%20This%20type%20of%20function,write%20to%20storage%20of%20contract) in the bytecode of the deployed contract.